# .env variable in the mounts section of devcontainer.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

setting up a `.devcontainer` configuration ...

I have a mount that normally lives in one spot, but when working remotely, can live in a different path. I want to set up a `devcontainer` so that I can change an environment variable locally, without making a commit change to the repos. I can't change the target because it is a convention that spans many tools and systems.

```
"mounts": [
  "type=bind,source=${localEnv:MY_DIR},target=/var/local/my_dir,readonly"
]
```

For example, in a `.env` file in the project root:

```
MY_DIR=~/workspace/my_local_dir
```

When I try this, no matter what combinations, this environment variable always ends up blank, and then Docker is sad when it gets a --mount configuration that is missing a source:

```
[2022-02-12T19:11:17.633Z] Start: Run: docker run --sig-proxy=false -a STDOUT -a STDERR --mount type=bind,source=,target=/var/local/my_dir,readonly --entrypoint /bin/sh vsc-sdmx-9c04deed4ad9f1e53addf97c69727933 -c echo Container started
[2022-02-12T19:11:17.808Z] docker: Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": field Source must not be empty.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

The reference shows that this type of syntax is allowed for a mount, and that a `.env` will be picked up by VSCode. But I guess it only does that for the running container and not VSC itself.

How do I set up a *developer-specific* configuration change?

Comment: People have been asking for the possibility to add environment variables since forever...
As of now, this issue is still open: 
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/2809

Answer (score 2):

The error message

```
invalid mount config for type "bind": field Source must not be empty
```

indicates that your `source` config appears empty to docker, which means that `${localEnv:MY_DIR}` resolves to an empty string, which in turn means that `MY_DIR` isn't set on your host, because "[Unset variables are left blank.](https://containers.dev/implementors/json_reference/#variables-in-devcontainerjson)".

If you set `MY_DIR` on your host then its path should be mounted into the devcontainer with the mount command you've used:

```
"mounts": [
  "type=bind,source=${localEnv:MY_DIR},target=/var/local/my_dir,readonly"
]
```

Defining a variable in an .env file in the project root, however, means that this variable gets set as an environment variable *in the devcontainer*, not locally.